# bootstrap input-group with select2 and css positioning

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

I'm trying to create a search box with a "drop down box" after the user insert search query into the input. It will make an ajax call and then create a drop down with some results.

I'm having some troubles using boostrap to do that.
Basically I want a structure like:

```
[CLOSE BUTTON][SELECT2][INPUT][SEARCHBTN]
```

The form is ready and working but I have two problems:
1- The select2 doesnt combine with input-group. If I insert it into input-group, it doesnt fit at all. The below code is what I have that works minimally, but it doesn't show like an input-group from bootstrap. It's showing as a separate select2. I'd like to make them seems the same "input".
2- I can't work in CSS to show a box with the results. It shows the results without box and in wrong scheme.

```
<div id="page-header-search" class="overlay-header">
<div class="content-header content-header-fullrow">
    <form action="/search/" method="post" id="search-query" name="search-query">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="layout" data-action="header_search_off">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
            <select class="js-select2 form-control input-group.input-group-sm" id="search_category" name="search_category" style="width: 10%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
                <option></option>
                    <?php ListMainCategories($link); ?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search or hit ESC.." id="search_text" name="search_text">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" id="resultados">
            <div class="results" id="results"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
.resultados .results{
position:relative;
width: 100%;
color: #313131;
font-family: Rubik, sans-serif;
font-weight: 300  
}

.resultados .results a{
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
border-bottom:1px solid #E0E0E0;
background-color: #ebebec;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;  
transition: all 275ms ease-in-out;
display: block;
cursor:pointer;
top:  0px;
right: 0px;
text-align: left;
/*border-radius: 40px;*/
transition: .5s ease-out;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

How can I make changes to get a good result?
How can I make the box with results seems an extension of the search input?
I can't get it working.

Comment: You need to put results and search input into the one `div` block. This is not the answer but the approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting closer :)